# How to redirect to settings page once the plugin is activated?

Tags: plugin-development, activation

I created the Plugin of my own. Everything seems OK but one thing I want to do in that plugin is redirect to the corresponding plugin settings page when the plugin is activate.

**For example:**
`http://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=rotator`

Is there a way to redirect to the corresponding page on activation, for example with `register_activation_hook`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe using the [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function in the activation hook. In the following example `myplugin_settings` is a placeholder. Normally this simply is the `$hook_suffix` you get back from `$hook_suffix = add_menu_page( /* etc. */ );`  and similar functions.

**THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK, READ BELOW**

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cyb_activation');
function cyb_activation()
{
    // Don't forget to exit() because wp_redirect doesn't exit automatically
    exit( wp_redirect( admin_url( 'options-general.php?page=myplugin_settings' ) ) );
}
```

References:

1. [Register activation hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)
2. [admin_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url)

**EDIT**

The redirect inside the activation hook seems to be performed before the plugin is effectively activated, maybe because of the call of exit() before the activation is executed. This code seems to work well using [activated_plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/activated_plugin) action hook:

```
function cyb_activation_redirect( $plugin ) {
    if( $plugin == plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) {
        exit( wp_redirect( admin_url( 'options-general.php?page=myplugin_settings' ) ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'cyb_activation_redirect' );
```

If you use this code outside the main plugin file you will need to replace `__FILE__` with path of the main plugin file.

**THOUGHT**

Redirecting the user after your plugin has been activated is not a very good approach. In Wordpress you can activate plugins in bulk. What happen then if you perform a redirect in this situation? You will break the activation of some plugins, maybe not if your plugin is the last being activated, but definitely you are breaking the user experience.

Comment: Much saner approach. +1

Comment: Anyone else getting an issue using this where the plugin fails to activate and you get a "You don't have permission to view this page" error instead? Am I hooking my menu page wrong? It seems like the `exit;` call is cutting the activation short.

Comment: The permission error is because you have not changed the redirection URL from `'options-general.php?page=myplugin_settings'` to something different and valid. Anyway, the `exit` in the activation hook is executed before the plugin is effectively activated, so it doesn't work. I've edited the answer with a new working code.

Comment: the code is resulting in header already sent..any way to fix it?

Comment: Thank you for this but I would use `wp_safe_redirect()` function.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_redirect');

function my_plugin_activate() {
    add_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', true);
}
// Solution 1
function my_plugin_redirect() {
    if (get_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
        delete_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
         wp_redirect("options-general.php?page=rotator");
         //wp_redirect() does not exit automatically and should almost always be followed by exit.
         exit;
    }
}

// OR

//Solution 2 (@kaiser suggestion)
function my_plugin_redirect() {
    if (get_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
        delete_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
         exit( wp_redirect("options-general.php?page=rotator") );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Even if it's a inline comment, remember:

> [wp_redirect()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) does not exit automatically and should almost always be
>   followed by exit.

**Specific example**

```
<?php
    wp_redirect( $location, $status );
    exit;
?>
```

**UPDATE 10/29/2013**

It was not mentioned, but please note that my solution offers the ability to check if is the case or not to do a redirect to plugin settings page.
Check `my_plugin_activate` and the if condition in `my_plugin_redirect`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `exit()` around the `wp_redirect()`?

Comment: @kaiser, answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

Hello i have used bellows code redirect after plugin activation. You can use this code. It's working nicely.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'nht_plugin_activate');
add_action('admin_init', 'nht_plugin_redirect');

function nht_plugin_activate() {
add_option('nht_plugin_do_activation_redirect', true);
}

function nht_plugin_redirect() {
if (get_option('nht_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
    delete_option('nht_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
    if(!isset($_GET['activate-multi']))
    {
        wp_redirect("edit.php?post_type=headline&page=news-headline");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: nht_ is my plugin prefix & "edit.php?post_type=headline&page=news-headline" is redirect page. please replace this those. You can see more tutorial on http://www.e2soft.com/